# Syling of the collection view background colour of items based on Bill type

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I want to give my collection view the same style of colour for the collection view items  as what is in the sync fusion calendar component how would i go about doing that i'm using a collection view. I have an item called BillType which will highlight and different colour red for health insurance blue for car insurance etc.

I would love to be able to style it the same the way it has the rounded corners

To be clear its the row of the collection view I want to alternate color based on the type

```
<CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Bills}"
            SelectionMode="None">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Padding="10"  x:DataType="model:Bills"> 
                    <Label Text="{Binding  Price}" 
                        LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                        Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                        FontSize="16" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Description}" 
                        LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                        Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                        FontSize="13" />
                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer 
                            NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                            Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:BillsViewModel}}, Path=ItemTapped}"     
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                        </TapGestureRecognizer>
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
    </RefreshView>
</StackLayout>
```

https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/calendar/calendar-events

[image]

I want to copy the purple and green from the calendar so the styling matches
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) to convert type to Color.

#### Converter

```
 public class TypeToColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var type = value as string;
            if (type == "xxx")
            {
                return Color.Green;
            }                
            else if(type == "aaa")
            {
                return Color.Purple;
            }

            return Color.White;
        }


        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return "";
        }

    }
```

#### Xaml

```
  <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:TypeToColorConverter  x:Key="c" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>


 
 <DataTemplate>
       <StackLayout Padding="10" BackgroundColor="{Binding type,Converter={StaticResource c}}">
```

Comment: Its not the stack layout i wish to change its the row of the collection view sorry if was not more clear

Comment: Can you post the image and highlight the part you want to change color.

Answer (score -1):

We would like to inform you that you can achieve your requirements of custom agenda view with collectionview.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:DateTimeToStringConverter x:Key="stringConverter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <local:CalendarBehavior/>
    </ContentPage.Behaviors>
  <StackLayout Padding="0,30,0,0">
   <syncfusion:SfCalendar x:Name="Calendar" ShowInlineEvents="false" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        <CollectionView x:Name="ListView">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0">
                                <Label Text = "{Binding StartTime, Converter={StaticResource stringConverter}}" FontSize="14" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding EndTime, Converter={StaticResource stringConverter}}" FontSize="14"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="40,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1">
                                <Label Text = "{Binding Subject}" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Behavior Class

```
public class CalendarBehavior : Behavior<ContentPage>
    {
        private SfCalendar calendar;
        CollectionView listView;
        private CalendarEventCollection calendarInlineEvents;
        private ObservableCollection<string> meetingSubjectCollection;
        private ObservableCollection<Color> colorCollection;
        public CalendarBehavior()
        {
            calendarInlineEvents = new CalendarEventCollection();
            this.AddAppointmentDetails();
            this.AddAppointments();
        }

        protected override void OnAttachedTo(ContentPage bindable)
        {
            var page = bindable as Page;
            calendar = page.FindByName<SfCalendar>("Calendar");
            listView = page.FindByName<CollectionView>("ListView");
            calendar.SelectionChanged += Calendar_SelectionChanged;
            listView.ItemsSource = GetSelectedDateAppointments(DateTime.Now.Date);
            // Setting Datasource for 3 Months.
            calendar.DataSource = calendarInlineEvents;
            base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        }

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(ContentPage bindable)
        {
            calendar.SelectionChanged -= Calendar_SelectionChanged;
            base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Calendars the selection changed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">Sender.</param>
        /// <param name="e">E.</param>
        void Calendar_SelectionChanged(object sender, Syncfusion.SfCalendar.XForms.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Setting ItemSource for ListView based on appointment selection
            listView.ItemsSource = GetSelectedDateAppointments(calendar.SelectedDate);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the selected date appointments.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The selected date appointments.</returns>
        /// <param name="date">Date.</param>
        public CalendarEventCollection GetSelectedDateAppointments(DateTime? date)
        {
            CalendarEventCollection selectedDateAppointments = new CalendarEventCollection();
            for (int i = 0; i < calendarInlineEvents.Count; i++)
            {
                DateTime startDate = calendarInlineEvents[i].StartTime;

                if (date.Value.Day == startDate.Day && date.Value.Month == startDate.Month && date.Value.Year == startDate.Year)
                {
                    selectedDateAppointments.Add(calendarInlineEvents[i]);
                }
            }
            return selectedDateAppointments;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds the appointment details.
        /// </summary>
        private void AddAppointmentDetails()
        {
            meetingSubjectCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            meetingSubjectCollection.Add("General Meeting");
            meetingSubjectCollection.Add("Plan Execution");
            meetingSubjectCollection.Add("Project Plan");
            meetingSubjectCollection.Add("Consulting");
            meetingSubjectCollection.Add("Support");
            meetingSubjectCollection.Add("Development Meeting");
            meetingSubjectCollection.Add("Scrum");
            meetingSubjectCollection.Add("Project Completion");
            meetingSubjectCollection.Add("Release updates");
            meetingSubjectCollection.Add("Performance Check");

            colorCollection = new ObservableCollection<Color>();
            colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FFA2C139"));
            colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FFD80073"));
            colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FF1BA1E2"));
            colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FFE671B8"));
            colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FFF09609"));
            colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FF339933"));
            colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FF00ABA9"));
            colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FFE671B8"));
            colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FF1BA1E2"));
            colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FFD80073"));
            colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FFA2C139"));
            colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FFA2C139"));
            colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FFD80073"));
            colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FF339933"));
            colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FFE671B8"));
            colorCollection.Add(Color.FromHex("#FF00ABA9"));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds the appointments.
        /// </summary>
        private void AddAppointments()
        {
            var today = DateTime.Now.Date;
            var random = new Random();
            for (int month = -1; month < 2; month++)
            {
                for (int day = -5; day < 5; day++)
                {
                    for (int count = 0; count < 2; count++)
                    {
                        var appointment = new CalendarInlineEvent();
                        appointment.Subject = meetingSubjectCollection[random.Next(7)];
                        appointment.Color = colorCollection[random.Next(10)];
                        appointment.StartTime = today.AddMonths(month).AddDays(random.Next(1, 28)).AddHours(random.Next(9, 18));
                        appointment.EndTime = appointment.StartTime.AddHours(2);
                        this.calendarInlineEvents.Add(appointment);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Date time to string converter.
    /// </summary>
    public class DateTimeToStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
            return dateTime.ToString("hh:mm tt");
        }

        object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```